# The Perfect Continuos Forms

Tags: present-perfect, present-perfect-progressive

I'm wondering are both of the variants correct?

1. Have you been waiting for me for a long time? / Have you been waiting for me long?
2. Have you fought again? (the result isn't visible at all) / Have you been fighting again? (it is obvious, e.g.: there are broken table and vase)
3. How long has your foot been hurting? / How long has your foot been hurting you?

I would like to know you point of view on both of them, but especially on the second one. I'm not a native so don't be mad at me is something is too explicit to be explained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) is correct.

Both versions of (2), with their respective interpretations, are fine. The present perfect continuous is clearer in that the action continues in the present, along with its consequences.

The sentences under (3) are ungrammatical. You should say:

3'. How long **has** your foot been hurting?

Note: In reply to you comment, "I'm not a native so don't be mad at me **if** something is too explicit to be explained," this is a site for EL **Learners**, so any potential responders should be patient and understanding as a rule.

Comment: I'll take it into consideration